# vector erase expects 2 arguments error

Tags: c++

I am using Code::Blocks and here is my code below in c++.

```
void removeEvenLength(vector<string> &vec)
{
    for (vector<string>::reverse_iterator i = vec.rbegin(); i != vec.rend(); ++i)
    {
        string word = *i;
        if (word.length() % 2 == 0)
            vec.erase(i);
    }
}
```

This function takes a vector of strings and removes the word that is even letters long. I get an error that says erase needs 2 arguments but according to the c++ documentation, one should be okay. Do you know what is wrong?

Comment: You know that if you modify a vector, iterators (and pointers) into it are invalidated? You might be able to use the return value of `erase` (see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)).

Comment: Use `std::remove_if`.

Comment: so if you cant use iterators or pointers to modify a vector, how can you loop through it and still remove elements from it without creating another vector?

Comment: You just can't use the same iterator after erasing. Honestly, `std::remove_if` gets rid of all of the problem already. It's quality, idiomatic code.

Comment: i looked at the documentation for remove_if and i don't understand how it would work. I tried rewriting the code as (next comment). The elements that I need to check are string from a vector.

Comment: void removeEvenLength(vector<string> &vec)
{
    remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), even);
}

bool even(const string &s)
{
    return s.length() == 2;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely must use `erase()` with a reverse iterator, here's how:

```
void removeEvenLength(vector<string> &vec)
{
    for (vector<string>::reverse_iterator i = vec.rbegin(); i != vec.rend();)
    {
        string word = *i;
        if (word.length() % 2 == 0) {
            vector<string>::iterator newi = vec.erase(i.base() - 1);
            i = vector<string>::reverse_iterator(newi);
        } else {
            ++i;
        }
    }
}
```

But that's not the best way to remove all even-length strings in a vector, for a number of reasons. The way to do that is as follows (it's called the "erase-remove" idiom):

```
struct IsEven {
    bool operator()(const string &s) const {
        return (s.size() % 2) == 0;
    }
};

vec.erase(
    std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), IsEven()),
    vec.end()
);
```

Or in C++11 you can use a lambda instead of a separate functor:

```
vec.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        vec.begin(), vec.end(), 
        [](const string &s) { return (s.size() % 2) == 0; }
    ),
    vec.end()
);
```

Comment: I have a few questions. First, why did you create a struct object in the first place? Second, I read through the documentation for remove_if and it stated that the third argument is a predicate function so how is it possible that you used IsEven() when it was only defined as a struct object. Third, I want to clarify the idea of vec.erase(). So the remove_if function returns the range of elements that make the predicate true (the pointer values) and all those elements are removed by the erase() method?

Comment: (1) You could do it with a function, but a struct or lambda is more friendly to inlining. (2) If the documentation you read says that `remove_if` must take a function, then it is incorrect. It will take anything that can be called. In this case an instance of `IsEven` can be called because it has overloaded `operator()`. In C++ this is called a functor. (3). Yes, `remove_if` returns the end of the range that are false, which therefore is also the start of the range that are true. The call to erase removes the true ones.

Answer (score 0):

If you see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) you will see that `erase` takes an `iterator` or a `const_iterator`, not a `reverse_iterator`. So you can't use it when iterating backwards.

Also, as suggested by chris in a comment, you might want to use [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead. The linked reference contains an example how to use it.